# Example of two homeomorphic spaces without a continuous deformation between them?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

on wikipedia it states:

> there need not be a continuous deformation for two spaces to be homeomorphic — only a continuous mapping with a continuous inverse function.

I'm trying to intuitively understand this difference between a continuous mapping and continuous deformation, so I'm trying to find an example of two spaces that are homeomorphic but without a continuous deformation.

Here is a definition of homotopy:

> Formally, a homotopy between two continuous functions f and g from a topological space X to a topological space Y is defined to be a continuous function H : X × [0,1] → Y from the product of the space X with the unit interval [0,1] to Y such that, if x ∈ X then H(x,0) = f(x) and H(x,1) = g(x)

**Does the following example satisfy?**

> [image]

In a sense there is no continuous deformation between the two (**though I honestly cannot immedately see from the definition why not. i.e. I cannot see why simply letting the different parts of the knot "move through" each other is not allowed by the formal definition of homotopy.**)

Comment: Don't you mean that the unknot at the trefoil knot can be continuously deformed into one another (somebody correct me if I'm wrong) but aren't homeomorphic? Then the reason why the two knots can't be homeomorphis is because they can't "move through" each other, because that would violate bijectivity I'm guessing

Comment: @Perturbative, that is definitely not what I meant, but it might be true. I've just started reading on these things so, I'm not sure...

Comment: @PaulFrost, so the unknot and the trefoil knot are (1) homeomorphic, (2) there is a homotopy between them, but (3) they are not isotopic? That would make sense. However, I'm still not sure if I can think of an example of two spaces that are homeomorphic but don't have a homotopy between them.

Comment: Wikipedia sometimes causes confusion. You quote the entries "Homeomorphism" and "Homotopy". The latter says that a continuous deformation is a homotopy between two maps $X \to Y$, the first gives an animated gif as an example. But this example should not be understood in the sense of the entry "Homotopy". You have two embeddings of the torus into $\mathbb{R}^3$  which are isotopic (i.e. all intermediate maps are embeddings) - it is much more than being homotopic. This is shown by the two knots above. They are homeomorphic as subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but the embeddings are not isotopic

Comment: @Programmer2134 A homeomorphism between spaces $X_1,X_2$ is completely independent from embeddings $f_i : X_i \to A$ into an ambient spaces $A$; you do not need the concept of homotopy. You can of course consider the images $Y_i = f_i(X_i)$ and try to deform them into each other (in the isotopic sense). But look at the space $A = [-1,0) \cup (0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Define embeddings $f_{\pm} : \lbrace 0 \rbrace \to A$ such that $f_{\pm}(0) = \pm1$. The subspaces $\lbrace -1 \rbrace$ and $\lbrace 1 \rbrace$ are certainly homeomorphic, but there is no homotopy between $f_+$ and $f_-$.

Comment: Another way to understand the "continuous deformation" of a subspace $X_0 \subset A$ into $X_1 \subset A$ is to require the existence of an isotopy $H : A \times [0,1] \to A$ such that $H_0 = id$ and $H_1(X_0) = X_1$ (ambient. isotopy). Perhaps this is what Wikipedia means. Clearly being ambient isotopic implies being homeomorphic.

Comment: @PaulFrost, I was under the impression that the set of pairs of topological spaces that are homeomorphic to eachother, is a strict superset of the set of such pairs that have a homotopy defined between them, and that this set is in turn a strict superset of those that are isotopic. Is this not the case? This is actually an assumption of my question, since I find it hard to come up with an example that is in the first set but not in the second.

Comment: @Programmer2134 What do you mean by a pair of spaces with a homotopy between them? There are only homotopies between maps, and if the maps are embeddings, then you also have isotopies between them. Do you perhaps mean homotopy equivalent spaces?

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Since this has gotten bumped:

tl; dr: Comparing *homeomorphism* (a relation between two topological spaces) and *homotopy* (a relation between two mappings) is a recipe for confusion. Informal, qualitative descriptions of topology do not help, since they frequently use language such as "continuous deformation", which can be interpreted in either sense.

---

Let $X$ and $Y$ be [topological spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Definition_via_open_sets), and let $f$, $g:X \to Y$ be [continuous mappings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces).

**Homeomorphism**: A mapping $f:X \to Y$ is a *homeomorphism* if $f$ is continuous and invertible, and its inverse is continuous. If there exists a homeomorphism $f:X \to Y$, we say the topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ are *homeomorphic*.

**Homotopy**: In the loosest sense, two continuous mappings $f$ and $g:X \to Y$ are *homotopic* if there exists a continuous mapping $H:X \times [0, 1] \to Y$ such that $H(x, 0) = f(x)$ and $H(x, 1) = g(x)$ for all $x$ in $X$.

(For technical reasons, it's usually desirable to fix a "basepoint" in each topological space and to assume all mappings send basepoints to basepoints, or in fancy terms *to work in the category of pointed spaces*. Since the aim here is merely to formalize qualitative descriptions of topology for posterity, we'll ignore basepoints.)

**Isotopy**: Along the lines of Paul Frost's comment, we can combine these two concepts. First, we say a mapping $f:X \to Y$ is an *embedding* if $f$ is a homeomorphism onto its image, i.e., an injective mapping with continuous inverse.

If $f$ and $g:X \to Y$ are embeddings, we say $f$ and $g$ are [*isotopic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Isotopy), or *homotopic through embeddings*, if there exists a homotopy $H:X \times [0, 1] \to Y$ such that for each $t$ with $0 \leq t \leq 1$, the mapping $H_{t} = H( \cdot, t):X \to Y$ is an embedding.

---

Let's see how these concepts differ.

1. The identity mapping $I_{X}:X \to X$ is a homeomorphism. Every mapping $f:X \to Y$ is homotopic to itself. Every embedding $f:X \to Y$ is isotopic to itself. A non-embedding $f:X \to Y$ is not isotopic to anything, because the definition above makes no sense for non-embeddings.
2. Any two mappings $f$, $g:X \to \Reals^{n}$ into a Cartesian space are homotopic (because we are working with "unpointed" spaces). The standard argument is to use the *straight line homotopy*
   $$
   H(x, t) = (1 - t)f(x) + tg(x) = f(x) + t(g(x) - f(x)),
   $$
   which connects the points $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ by a line segment, and then simultaneously "deforms" along these segments as $t$ runs from $0$ to $1$.
3. Let $X$ denote the unit circle, which we'll represent as the set of points $(x, y) = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ in the Cartesian plane.

- The *antipodal mapping* $g(x, y) = (-x, -y)$ is a homeomorphism of the circle to itself, hence an embedding. The mapping
  $$
  H((x, y), t) = (x\cos\pi t - y\sin\pi t, x\sin\pi t + y\cos\pi t),
  $$
  which rotates the circle counterclockwise through angle $\pi t$, is an isotopy from the identity to the antipodal mapping.
- The *reflection mapping* $g(x, y) = (x, -y)$ is a self-homeomorphism of the circle, but turns out not to be homotopic (much less isotopic) to the identity. To prove this, we need some "homotopy invariant" of mappings, some number or other mathematical structure associated to a continuous mapping in a way that homotopic mappings have the same invariant, and so that these mappings have different invariants. Doing so is beyond the scope of this answer, but a standard choice is *winding number*. Intuitively, the identity mapping "winds $+1$ times" (i.e., once counterclockwise) while $g$ winds $-1$ times (once clockwise).
- The *inclusion mapping* of the circle into the plane $\Reals^{2}$ and the reflection mapping of the circle into the plane *are* homotopic *as mappings into the plane*. Indeed, Point 2. above guarantees that any two mappings $f$, $g:X \to \Reals^{2}$ are homotopic. One point is, whether or not two mappings are homotopic depends on the "ambient space" $Y$.
- The trefoil knot, which may be parametrized by
  $$
    G(\theta) = \frac{1}{1 + r_{2}\sin 3t}{(r_{1}\cos2\theta, r_{1}\sin 2\theta, r_{2}\cos 3\theta)},\ r_{1}^{2} + r_{2}^{2} = 1,
    $$
  is the image of an embedding $g$ of the circle into $\Reals^{3}$. (The mapping $G$ is continuous in $\theta$, and injective as a mapping on the circle, since two values of $\theta$ map to the same location if and only if they differ by an integer multiple of $2\pi$. Since the circle is [*compact*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space), the inverse mapping $g^{-1}$ is continuous.) By Point 2., any two embeddings of the circle into $\Reals^{3}$ are homotopic. Particularly, the mapping $f(x, y) = (x, y, 0)$ and mapping $g$ from the circle to the trefoil are homotopic. It turns out, however, that these mappings are not isotopic. To prove this, we would need an *isotopy invariant* of mappings that can distinguish the unknot from the trefoil knot.

[image: Homotopy of the unknot and the trefoil as mappings into three-space]

---

The proper notion of *topological equivalence* depends on context, and quickly becomes subtle even in situations, such as a plane circle and a trefoil knot, that appear qualitative and simple.

- As *topological spaces* the circle and the trefoil are homeomorphic. In this sense, the circle and trefoil knot are "topologically equivalent".
- As *mappings of the circle* into $\Reals^{3}$, the circle and trefoil are homotopic, i.e., "deformable into each other through continuous mappings".
- As *embeddings of the circle* into $\Reals^{3}$, the circle and trefoil are not isotopic, i.e., "cannot be deformed into each other" through embeddings.

Comment: hi! regarding point 2, even if any two mappings $f,g$ to $\mathbb{R^3}$ are homotopic, can we say that their images in $\mathbb{R^3}$ are not necessarily homotopy equivalent (take for instance $f$ as the inclusion of the circle in $\mathbb{R^3}$ and $g$ a constant mapping to a point of $\mathbb{R^3}$) ? also, are instead the unknot and the trefoil knot homotopy equivalent? lastly, can we say that the images of two embeddings $f_e, g_e$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$ are homotopy equivalent? thanks